# fade element out with css and javascript leaves empty space in page

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to just use vanilla javascript instead of jQuery and to fade an element out I am using css and js.

My css:

```
.fade-out {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

The js:

```
        const approveBox = document.querySelector('.dashboard-list-box');
        approveBox.classList.add('fade-out');
```

This works but the problem is that it leaves a gaping hole in the page when the element fades out instead of shifting the content below upwards like it would with using jQuery fadeOut().

If I replace visibility: hidden with

```
display: none
```

Then it just disappears instantly without fading. Is there a way around this?

Comment: make the height 0 after your animation done. Or put height:0 in your css fade-out class

Comment: @MustKeemJ, thanks for this. The problem is that the height becomes 0 before the transition is complete and that doesn't look so good